# Django calling same view out of multiple views for a template

Tags: django

I have a template which calls multiple views. But for some reason, the same view is being called. I'm not able to figure it out.

Template : schedule.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Schedule Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Today's Schedule </h1>

    <b>Scheduled Appointments:</b>
    <div>
        {% for p in schedule %}
            <p> {{p.id}}  {{p.name}} {{p.surname}}  {{p.appointment_time }} </p>
            {% if p.status == "Arrived" %}
                <p>Patient Arrived</p>
                <!-- <button>See Patient</button> -->
                <form action="{% url 'see_patient' p.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="appid" value="{{ p.id }}">
                    <input type="submit" value="See Patient" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            {% elif p.status == 'In Session' %}
                <p>In Progress</p>
                <form action="{% url 'complete' p.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="{{ p.id }}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Complete" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            {% elif p.status == 'Complete' %} 
                <p>Completed</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>{{p.status}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</br>



</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
def see_patient(request, appid):
    print("See Patient", appid)
    app = CheckAppointments()
    app.update_appointment_status(appid, {'status' : 'In Session'})
    appointment_obj =  Appointments.objects.get(appointment_id = appid)
    appointment_obj.status = "In Session"
    update_wait_time(request)

    return redirect('/schedule/')

def appointment_complete(request, app_id):
    print("Complete:", app_id)
    app = CheckAppointments()
    app.update_appointment_status(app_id, {'status' : 'Complete'})
    appointment_obj = Appointments.objects.get(appointment_id = app_id)
    appointment_obj.status = "Complete" 
    appointment_obj.save()
    resume_time(request)
    return redirect('/schedule/')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^schedule/$', views.ScheduledAppointments.as_view(), name='schedule'),
    url(r'^schedule/(?P<appid>\d+)/$', views.see_patient, name='see_patient'),
    url(r'^schedule/(?P<app_id>\d+)/$', views.appointment_complete, name='complete'),
```

When I click on "complete" the POST Request is still being sent to see_patient view instead of appointment_complete.

Comment: How is Django supposed to know which view to route to if you register them both with the same regular expression? Typically I would differentiate these by adding `/complete` or some other suffix to the URL for the `appointment_complete` view.

Comment: The url will match with see_patient that is first on the list and only that one. It won't call two views

Comment: Understood. Thanks.